# OData V4 property access

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2, scaffolding

I have created a very primitive OData webservice using a Visual Studio 2015 Web API 2 project and a scaffolded controller ("Microsoft OData V4 Web API Controller Using Entity Framework" scaffolding).

I have only one entity set in my model: "Books". The "Book" entity has a privimtive "Title" string property.

I presumed that the scaffolded controller would serve all legal OData v4 requests, but that seems not to be the case?

http://localhost:xxxx/OData/Books works (enumerates all books with all properties - including the "Title" property)

http://localhost:xxxx/OData/Books(1) works (enumerates all properties on the first book, including the "Title" property)

http://localhost:xxxx/OData/Books(1)/Title **does not work** - I get a **"No routing convention was found to select an action for the OData path with template '~/entityset/key/property"** error, despite that the request is 100% OData v4 complaint?

Why doesn't it work? Shouldn't it work? What will it take to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scaffolding does **not** create a controller that serves all legal OData v4 requests.

To retrieve the Title property of a Book entity, you must add a method to the `BooksController` as follows:

```
public string GetTitleFromBook([FromODataUri] int key) 
{
    // Put appropriate method logic here.
}
```

See "Querying a Navigation Property" and "Properties" tables in [Routing Conventions in ASP.NET Web API 2 Odata](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/odata-routing-conventions).

Also, consider using the [`$select` query option](http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata02/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata02-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc406398163) to limit the properties you get in response to a normal request for an entity. For example:

```
GET http://localhost:xxxx/OData/Books(1)?$select=Title
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the link - now I think I get it. Will it be right to say, that in order to handle requests for *any* single property of an entity, the controller for that entity must implement a separate specialized action method of the form "Get<PropertyName>From<EntityName>(...)" for each and every property available?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are using the built-in routing convention for entity properties. As an alternative, you could write your own routing convention that supports passing the property name as a string to your controller method, but that's much more work.

Comment: An option is to use a T4 template to generate out these standard property and navigation access links if you wish to use them. It's pretty generic code that is useful in some applications but only if you get it write, once you have more than 5 or 6 tables that becomes a lot of hand written plumbing code.